# References about profiled deviance components

Tags: r, mixed-model, profile-likelihood

I have read the excellent slides ["Assessing the precision of estimates of variance
components"](http://lme4.r-forge.r-project.org/slides/2009-07-21-Seewiesen/4PrecisionD.pdf) from  Douglas Bates.

I'm looking for some references about these *profiled deviance components* (for instance I'd like to understand why [what does it mean that] `ldL2` measures the complexity of the model and why [what does it mean that] `lprss` measures the fidelity to the data ?)

I have already asked this question to the r-sig-mixed-models list but nobody has answered.